# Reduce kubernetes Persistent Volumes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, devops

I am using multiple apps on kubernetes and all are configured with `pd-ssd` volume. Some deployments are running on big volume with less data. So i wanted to reduce that volume of the pods. I have worked with increase volumen and it was worked. But i can't reduce the space of the volume.

Steps i did. Current size is 100Gi, I want to resize it to 30Gi.

1. Scaling down the application and pod.
2. edit pvc to reduce the size of volume.

```
k edit pvc my-pvc
```

I got the following error when I save the changes.

> error: persistentvolumeclaims "my-pvc" is invalid
>   A copy of your changes has been stored to "/tmp/kubectl-edit-4ivk1.yaml"
>   error: Edit cancelled, no valid changes were saved.

But i can not able to save the changes for reduce volume size.

Answer (score 6):

Shrinking persistent volumes is **not** supported in kubernetes, you can only increase it.
[resizing-persistent-volumes-using-kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/12/resizing-persistent-volumes-using-kubernetes/)

Comment: That may perhaps be. However, what should we do if there is a need to downsize the volume? (e.g., for cost savings) Is there some sort of workaround, or does the volume content need to be backed up somewhere, the new volume created with new smaller size, and the content restored from the back-up? Is there a simpler way?

Comment: I would have done the way you suggested. Unfortunately I am not familiar with the simpler way yet.

Comment: Here's what I have ended up doing: 1) create a new pvc with name="<original>-backup" of the new, smaller size; 2) connect that backup pvc to the deployment (so that both original and backup are connected); 3) turn on read-only maintenance mode for the service; 4) execute the copy of the files from original to backup; 5) delete original pvc connection and pvc itself; 6) create new pvc of lower size with the same name="<original>"; 7) reconnect it to the service; 8) disable read-only mode; 9) check if works; 10) disconnect and delete the backup pvc.